# how to set encoding after using move_uploaded_file?

Tags: php, character-encoding

i am saving a file using `move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $save_path . $FileName);` but when the file name i choose is in arabic , the file is saved in strange characters like that : `ÒíäÈ.pdf`.

so when i try to open the uploaded file later, it says file not found .(the real one) what should i do ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will be better to rename the image name using time stamp

```
$imgname = time().'.'.'jpg';
$imgtmpname=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fullpath= $path.$imgname;
$filename = $imgname;
move_uploaded_file($imgtmpname,$fullpath);
```

and also store the `$imgname` in the database so we can fetch the image by this name..It will also avoid the name conflict between images as the timestamps keep changing.

Comment: ok thanks, so there is no other solution than renaming the file ??

Comment: I'd rather save the filename to a database with a unique, sequence number, and name the image by that number. Your solution has potential for concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can use transliteration on any string you want to **convert** to latin-similar characters. My **very-custom** transliteration code looks like that:

```
// convert a utf8-encoded string into latin representative 
function transliterate_string($params=array())
{
   // PARAMS:  "string", "language"

   // 0) fill-in "native" chars by language and their "latin" representative
   $SP_trans = array(
      "ae"=>array("native"=>"ة,بْ,...","latin"=>"a,b,..."),
      ...other langs if you want
   );

   // 1) break "native" & "latin" strings
   $nc = explode(",",$SP_trans[ $params["language"] ]["native"]);
  $lc = explode(",",$SP_trans[ $params["language"] ]["latin"]);
  // 2) convert to lower first
  $string = mb_strtolower($params["string"],"utf-8");
  // 3) loop each character   
  mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
  for($x=0,$sz=mb_strlen($string);$x<$sz;$x++) {
     $char = mb_substr($string,$x,1);
     $index = array_search($char,$nc);  
     $out[$x] = ($index===FALSE ? $char : $lc[$index]);
  }
  return trim(implode("",$out));
}
```

the function just scans a string and convert each character of specific character
set into **latin** in a custom way. Then you can `safely` save the file as latin.